# How to convert string to date in format yyyymmdd

Tags: excel

I have dates stored as text/string in the format yyyymmdd e.g. 20190104 and I would like to convert this to the excel date format. I tried applying a custom format of yyyymmdd to no avail.

I am currently using

```
=Date(LEFT(x,4),MID(x,5,2),RIGHT(x,2))
```

Comment: `=Date(LEFT(x,4),MID(x,5,2),RIGHT(x,2))`? Because year is 4 digits long, then month from digit 5 in length 2?

Answer (score 2):

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT("20190104","0000-00-00"))
```

or as @Axel commented:

```
=DATE(LEFT("20190104",4),MID("20190104",5,2),RIGHT("20190104",2))
```

Comment: In my opinion providing dates in `YYYYMMDD` format without any delimiter is bad habit since 20190104 easily can be confused with a number as Excel will do. Correct international date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I'd agree with that.  I think I spend more time finding bad data than I do creating reports sometimes.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Correct international date format (according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates)) can either be `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD`. Although your point about how Excel interprets the value still stands (and `YYYYMMDD` is hardly the most human-readable format).